# button click event in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a button and a label.
on clicking on that button i want to change the text of label.
How can i do this in Asp.net mvc 1.0.

Comment: Do you want this to be changed client-side or server side? Where is the data coming from?

Comment: i want to do this in server side.

Comment: Do you have <asp:Label id="Label1" runat="server"/> and <asp:Button id="Button1" runat="server" /> or you have an <input type="submit" /> and <span>?

Comment: you should check out the videos over at www.asp.net/mvc for an introduction to basic MVC.. Best place to start!

MVC does not behave the way one is used to from Webforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike in ASP.NET Webforms, there are no events in ASP.NET MVC!

You could use `HtmlHelper.ActionLink` to create a link to the current view with a parameter containing the new label text.

For simple things that don't really deserve a parameter I would simply use JavaScript though.